# The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "DB_PROD_04" was unable to begin a distributed transaction

Tags: sql, t-sql, linked-server, distributed-transactions

I have two servers:

> SQL_UAT_01
>
> DB_PROD_04

Both of these servers have the same database name and same tables:

> SQL_UAT_01.Database_01.TestTable
>
> DB_PROD_04.Database_01.TestTable

There is a trigger on each of these two tables.

When the trigger fires, it does a simple UPDATE on the table of the OTHER server.

**Example**

Trigger is fired here:

> SQL_UAT_01.Database_01.Test

It does an update here:

> DB_PROD_04.Database_01.Test

And vice-versa.

I'm running into an error which I have no clue how to fix.

**Again, the error is this:**

> CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call
>   spGetAndIncrementIndex(?)}]; nested exception is
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The operation could
>   not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server
>   "DB_PROD_04" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

I have already linked the servers on both sides.

Does anyone have ANY idea how I should go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to install the DT on the server. It's a windows feature. I installed it and wahllah!

Comment: What's 'DT' please?

Answer (score 0):

If a server runs out of local ports, you also get MSDTC issues

This is also fixed by correcting ephemeral TCP port saturation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610%28v=bts.20%29.aspx